# Word 2016: Cannot work with SharePoint files

Tags: microsoft-word

When I open a file from SharePoint the files is opened in read-only mode in Word 2016. I can only choose for the "Save as..." feature. There is no bar or elevation possible to switch to read/write access.

Additionally, when I try to navigate straight to the document library, by pasting in the specific url into the Open Document dialog, I arrive at the Documents-folder of my local machine.

How can I troubleshoot this further?
Everything works fine in Word 2013!

Using SharePoint Server 2013 October 2015 CU

Comment: I feel this is a bit off topic for this site, since it regards the client software Word 2016 rather than SharePoint.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint? Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: How do I add screenshots?

Comment: @Carlin'tVeld Upload your image to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get a link you can share. [Edit] your question to include this link and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image for you.